# Ubuntu 16.04 on dell inspiron internet drops but wifi keeps connected. Network is confirmed to be OK

Tags: 16.04, networking, internet, dell, laptop

I have already looked for similar questions, but nearly all of them are about previous versions of Ubuntu.

After some amount of time, and usually but not always inactivity, Ubuntu stops downloading and uploading, while still conneceted on the wifi. If I click on the same network's name, it reconnects and works fine. I am using default drivers for network, and third-party options for that do not appear as available.

This has happened over many different networks, to all of which mine and my girfriend's phones are connected without problems. Also, this started to happen just after a fresh ubuntu install, so the chances of this being a network problem are virtually zero.

As I said, I looked for similar questions, but mine is a very specific one, and it differs from all of the ones I found.

If you could please help me, I am very annoyed to leave the house and come back to failed dropbox uploads and idle torrents.

Thank you all so very much for your time

output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 79)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:4410]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: In a terminal window, use `journalctl -b >j.tmp` to save all the system log messages since boot into `j.tmp`. Read the file with `less j.tmp` (read `man less first) and see what you find.

Comment: @Pilot6, sorry for the delay, I am traveling. Just did what you asked. It  does not appear to explain the problem, or am I wrong? What should I do now? Thanks!